# Tracking codes go corrupt or disappear - how to test automatically and be notified

Tags: automated-testing

I have many Google Analytics tracking codes, for links, buttons etc, which are based mostly on elements classes and IDs. If our coder do new commits, these tracking codes often go corrupt - are just away (and don't fire at all) or changed (like a div name is assigned to another element and tracking is fired wrongly) or the like.

I want to run before each commit an automated test and be notified if things I defined aren't in their place.

I use for low scale quasi manual tests Charly Proxy and/or Fiddler as Hit Validators - but I need to move to automation of such tests, and automation of error reportings.

Any recommendation is higly welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) a Continuous integration automation tool, that runs an automated tests when a commit or build is deployed on the environment or you can schedule a Test run on daily or weekly basis.

Also when you connect your automation tool with any reporters tools like Extent Reports, Allure Report for tracking the results, I would suggest if you are using a build tool as [MAVEN](https://maven.apache.org/) then it will be very easy for integrating the project with the reporters and also with continuous integration tool like Jenkins.

Suppose if you are a beginner in automation then you may use [Katalon studio](https://www.katalon.com/) that supports Web, Mobile and API testing in the same tool and you can generate report in the same tool. You can also integrate Katalon studio with jenkins using the following [link](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/jenskins-ci-integration/). Another tool is [Endtest](https://endtest.io/) which is a codeless automation tool where you can create automated tests to run the code and also you can export the results also.

Answer (score 2):

"If our coder do new commits, these tracking codes often go corrupt - are just away (and don't fire at all) or changed (like a div name is assigned to another element and tracking is fired wrongly)"

I would talk to your coders.  Why do they think this happens?  How do they maintain the tracking codes?  How do they think they could improve the process?  How do they deal with moving a tracking code around a page? Do they know that these issues are happening?

Other companies are able to deal with tracking codes for Google without these issues so there is probably some education and training needed.

Comment: if it would be possible to avoid errors just by talking to coders, i surely would do it at first

Comment: That sounds a bit sarcastic.  Remember, we're trying to help you for free.  Your question did not indicate any discussions with developers, correct?  If you want help, help us first with some humble answers.